# Logistic Regression Power Analysis with Multiple Predictors

Tags: logistic, sample-size, statistical-power, binary-data

So I'm working on my dissertation and I'm trying to figure out a binary logistic regression power analysis to show how many participants I should collect. My proposed analysis is as follows and the range of sample sizes I've gotten. **My question is, am I doing this correctly using R and if not, where would you suggest modifications.**

There are 3 binary outcomes: past, present, and future treatment seeking (answered as yes/no during interview).
To run this power analysis in R, there were two packages I could use (powerMediation and WebPower). Both packages required finding values that represent the probability of observing 1 for the outcome variable Y when predictor X equals 1 (p1) and probability of observing 1 for the outcome variable Y when predictor X equals 0 (p0). As the literature did not explicitly look at the proposed predictors, and a pilot study has not been done, I had to make some assumptions for these values based on what the prior literature showed based on mental health treatment utilization.
I have several predictors that are all continuous variables. Ideally, I would run these together with each out my 3 outcomes (so 3 tests overall), but I'm not seeing where any of the power analyses take multiple predictors into consideration.

For WebPower this is the formula I was using:
wp.logistic(p0=*value*, p1=*value*, alpha=0.05,
power=0.80, alternative="two.sided", family="normal")

For powerMediation this is the formula I was using:
SSizeLogisticBin(p1 = *value*, p2 = *value*,
B = 0.5, alpha = 0.05,
power = 0.8)

The range of values I used are below. The range of sample sizes vary from as low as 21 participants to as high as 1907 participants.

[image]

Comment: Make sure it's a hypothesis testing project and not an estimation one.  Power is only for the former.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Hi! Thanks for the comment. So I believe I am doing hypothesis testing as I have specific predictions for my outcomes. Is that what you are referring to? Or suggesting that I reframe the question to estimation?

Comment: Null hypothesis testing = signal detection = trying to bring evidence against the supposition that effect = 0 as if you are interested in even trivial nonzero effects.  Estimation = estimating partial effects (odds ratios) or estimating probabilities of outcomes as a function of X.  Sample size can be chosen for providing sufficient precision for a specific probability estimate or for achieving an overall accurate model as detailed [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/sim.7992).